# Efficient way to take a dense NumPy array and replace the values above a given line and below anoth with Nan?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

(not my image took it offline for example)[kriging plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fiXI.png)
I have a plot that looks like this and I need to replace all the data in the corners defined by the two redlines with Nans in python. Is there an efficient way to do this?

I am away of a way to do it by defining two linear function and checking where they lie in relatively with cross product and then iterating that for every point but it is horrendously slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I created a mask of the area between the lines and use it to set the values of the original array to NaN where the mask is zero:

```py
import numpy as np

def nan_outside_lines(arr, line1_m, line1_b, line2_m, line2_b):
    # create a mask of the area under each line
    x = np.arange(arr.shape[1])
    y = np.arange(arr.shape[0])
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    mask_under_line_1 = yy < line1_m*xx + line1_b
    mask_under_line_2 = yy < line2_m*xx + line2_b

    # now to get the area between the two lines, we can XOR the two masks
    mask_between_lines = np.logical_xor(mask_under_line_1, mask_under_line_2)

    # now we can set the values in the area outside both lines to NaN
    result = arr.copy()
    result[~mask_between_lines] = np.nan

    return result
```

#### Testing the solution

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

arr = np.random.rand(110,100)   # 2d array to transform

# test it out with 10 random lines
for i in range(10):
    line1_slope = np.random.rand() * 3 - 1.5  # random slope between -1.5 and 1.5
    line1_intercept = np.random.rand() * 80   # random y-intercept between 0 and 80
    line2_slope = np.random.rand() * 3 - 1.5  # random slope between -1.5 and 1.5
    line2_intercept = np.random.rand() * 80   # random y-intercept between 0 and 80

    transformed = nan_outside_lines(arr, line1_slope, line1_intercept, line2_slope, line2_intercept)

    plt.imshow(transformed)
    plt.plot([0,110],[line1_slope*0+line1_intercept,line1_slope*110+line1_intercept],color='red')
    plt.plot([0,110],[line2_slope*0+line2_intercept,line2_slope*110+line2_intercept],color='red')
    plt.title(f"result for y={line1_slope:.3g}x+{line1_intercept:.3g}"
              f" and y={line2_slope:.3g}x+{line2_intercept:.3g}")

    # clip domain to 0-100 and range to 0-110 for visualization
    plt.xlim(0,100)
    plt.ylim(0,110)
    plt.show()
```

#### Sample output from the test plots

[image: Sample output plots]

Comment: That looks perfect thank yo so much!

Comment: The line 'result[~mask_between_lines] = np.nan' is returning the error  "boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 4100 but corresponding boolean dimension is 900"

Comment: I should clarify that the array is not square its ~4100x900

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the function to work with arrays that don't have the same width and height. It uses the longest side to make a square mask then trims the mask before applying the inverse mask to the array. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: `meshgrid` can take two unequal arrays, so `xrange = np.arange(arr.shape[1])` and `yrange = np.arange(arr.shape[0])` should work without needing any trimming of the mask

Comment: @Pranav thanks for pointing this out. Just edited